# PHP: Moving a script to another directory messes up its includes

Tags: php, include, directory

How can I always include other source files regardless of where the current is located in the directory structure?

Comment: define a constant that will represent the path to your base directory `define('BASE_DIR', '/var/www/path/to/your/dir');` and then use this constant while including all the other files

Comment: @naiquevin: But you'd need to define that constant in all your scripts, which would be a maintenance nightmare!

Comment: You should have a view file such as index.php which this would be defined within and every file that stems down from this would have access to the constant.

Comment: @Robert: "You should"?  Says who?

Comment: Says the principle of view files within a website, A view file is the trigger a user uses to initialize a web application, there has to be at least one or your site would not function, if you have several view files so be it, and you would tend to have 1 global included file such as constants or config, you would be able to define the constant there.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - i was thinking on the lines of having a config file which will be included in all the files and define the constant(s) in it. without mentioning the config file part, my above answer is incomplete. apologies

Comment: @naiquevin: And how do you include that file?!

Comment: you would require it relative to the working directory, for example `require_once 'config.php';` which in turn would set out all the constants for your environment.

Comment: @Robert: But doesn't that rely on exactly the problem the OP is trying to solve?  What if the source file moves location?  What if the cwd has been modified?  (Actually, I suppose the latter is unlikely assuming you put all your includes before any real code, like a sane person...)

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth oops! I assumed MVC or some framework :) sorry again ini_set() might help perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute paths instead of relative ones. Preferably by using a baseURL setting somewhere in your config.

Comment: I had to go look up about absolute paths.  Wasn't even aware of those in this context.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set the [include_path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path); that way your includes will occur invariant of the current script location.

Comment: The problem is that if you migrate server you have to reset up all the paths again.

Comment: @RobertPitt: Oh no!  You have to set a single string!  How does that differ from any other configuration that will need to be replicated?

Comment: Why the sarcasm, what if the OP does not have access to the ini ?

Comment: @Robert: Sarcasm because the problem you specified isn't really a unique one when it comes to migrating server.  The problem of not having access to the ini file is a valid one, however.  But without some sort of external reference (like the ini file), there's no good way to solve this problem.

Comment: include_path is a lame crutch for ones who can't organize their files, and just do not know where to find it

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Maybe. But it also allows you the flexibility to move things around with respect to one another, without the headache of updating every single reference to it.

Comment: I have not such a headaches and never used that setting. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Clearly you're a genius then! ;)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: To elucidate.  It strikes me as a fairly grim idea to hard-code relative references into source files that rely on the current location.  I wouldn't do this in C or C++; I see no reason to make life (potentially) hard for oneself in PHP either!

Comment: I also do not have headaches, in fact I would expect more headache using the `include_path`

Answer (score 1):

For a PHP project, I would always set a document root for my project - eg. '/home/project' and then include all includes relative to that document root.

Answer (score 0):

With a single point of entry (e.g. index.php is always the first script to be loaded), your best bet would indeed be using the include path and determining the path the path to put in there by finding the directory the current file resides in. That means that you can include files relative from the index.php file, without using a constant. The other upside is that when you move all the scripts, the include_path will be set to it's *new* location. Here's what I'd do.

```
<?php
set_include_path(
    dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . get_include_path( )
);
?>
```

Now, if you don't have a single point of entry (e.g. contact.php is requested directly), you might be better of using a config-file, which will do the same as the above: change the include_path. The downside of this is that you'll have to include that config file in each and every file, but the upside is that you can move the files, without changing a single thing. Just put above code in config.php and include that in every file that is publically approachable.

There is a third way, and that's the one I always use for library files, as you can't be sure whether or not it will be used, and you can't be sure in what directory it lives. Use relatively absolute file includes. I know that sounds funny, but what I'm trying to say is that if you include files like this, you won't ever have a problem:

```
<?php
require_once realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) )  . '/exception.php';
```

Good luck!

Comment: `you'll have to include that config file in each and every file` doesn't it spoil the whole idea of automatic include?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, Would you care to create a reply instead of down voting others attempts to make the OP's life easier, we all have different methods, None of them are incorrect, and all of them work, were voting upon the **best** answer sir.

Comment: The question is not about "automatic includes", the question is: "How can I always include other source files regardless of where the current is located in the directory structure?".

I think my answer lists three different methods to be able to include files, regardless of where on the file-system they are located. And, I agree with RobertPitt, a reply (or question) is much more appreciated than a (unnecessary?) down-vote.

Answer (score -1):

To get the best possible root path you should define a constant in your view file, i.e (index.php) and you should make it cross platform compatible.

after the years working in PHP and multi platform applications I discovered the best method to do this is a combination of the following native PHP Functions and constants:

- define
- str_replace
- dirname
- `__FILE__`

Heres why we use the functions:

- The reason why we use define is to allow the document root to stay within the global scope
- The reason for `str_replace` is to change the slashes to be cross platform compatible
- The reason for `dirname` is to help the relative path to the root view file
- The reason for `__FILE__` is to discover the view file for `dirname`

We could use `__DIR__` for PHP5 but `__FILE__` is better as it would support previous versions of windows.

Fully combined you would have a valid relative path to your view file.

```
define("ROOT_PATH",str_repalce("\\","/",dirname(__FILE__)));
```

this would produce the perfect relative path to your index directory without the trailing slash, you should then include your files like so:

```
require_once ROOT_PATH . "/system/classes/some.class.php";
```

In windows both `/` and `\` are valid, and for other operating systems its just `/`, so generally you should always build your applications with the `/` as your directory separator.

Comment: and what if i do not have access to php.ini ?

Comment: Why not use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` and save yourself some hassles?

Comment: Because its ugly and long, and what hassle, using `/` is proven to work on all systems

Answer (score -1):

Set define variable in your header files. then use that define variable when required
like

```
define('BASE_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project/modules/module.php');
```

you can define $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to get your document root path. then give your project name and path to that file.

Comment: You will need to define this in each script, which sounds like a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: and how to set path to that header file?

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth: you may have missed which I have written in my post, that is set defined variable in header file, which state that this define should be written in header(means some common file) which gets include on each script.

Comment: @  Col. Shrapnel : you just have to define BASE_PATH as i have stated in any comman file which gets induce on every script. then start using that BASE_PATH variable where ever required.